# Gentoo can't boot on GRUB2

Tags: linux, boot, grub, gentoo

Gentoo is on /dev/sda4 and /dev/sda3 is /boot,/boot/kernel-genkernel-x86-3.18.7-gentoo and /boot/initramfs-genkernel-x86-3.18.7-gentoo both are genkernel-built,but GRUB says:could not find the root device in /dev/sda4.
Here is my fstab:https://pastebin.anthonos.org/view/6958e8c8 (Already tried to replace /dev with UUID,not work)
And this grub.cfg:https://pastebin.anthonos.org/view/639f93dd
grub can load Windows,so I'm sure that grub's binary isn't broken.
What to do?

Comment: is the UUID of your Gentoo partition ab8313f8-2c6d-4f60-88a0-f3d8e1472437 ? If not then that explains your problem...

Comment: @gogoud What's the problem?I didn't see this UUID when grub report error,this should be /boot's UUID

Comment: can you give the exact message you see when grub gives up? does it drop to a grub shell prompt?

Comment: @gogoud I can't get screenshot because I don't have a cam,It just showed could not find the root device in (Depends on fstab set),and says Press Enter for the same ,'shell' to into shell,and 'q' to skip.No kernel panic.

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-zcRMjslRR-g/VPdItFzSGyI/AAAAAAAAI44/ISdfToSPTE0/w506-h380/5%2B-%2B1

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, that is helpful because we can google the actual text you are seeing. Maybe some help here: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-919588-start-0.html

Comment: and especially (because very recent) here: https://github.com/mbusb/multibootusb/issues/14

Comment: @gogoud tried to add livecd..fail

Comment: Did you create a custom kernel? If so, make sure you compiled in support for your serial ATA device and the filesystem you are using for your root partition (ext3, ext4, reiserfs, etc) otherwise the kernel won't know how to find your root partition.

Comment: I did a fresh Gentoo install recently and one thing that got me into a similar situation was using a GPT instead of an MBR partition type and then not enabling support for GPT in the kernel as laid out in the kernel step of the handbook. You should perhaps retry making your kernel and use `genkernel --menuconfig all` to go into the menuconfig and make sure ext4 is enabled and then verify that the GPT or UEFI config is set as the handbook says if that applies to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.Because Genkernel(not Genkernel-next)doesn't contain ext4fs support.Since I complied kernel myself,solved.